# How can I execute functional tests as part of CICD pipeline

Tags: java, selenium, qaf

In my organisation I have created a test automation using qaf (qmetry automation framework). My target is to run this functional test cases automatically in CICD pipeline. We have a system where when code check-in was complete then the Jenkins tool will trigger the functional test cases automatically and it runs in available VDI. We have 20-30 VDI out of which it will pick one and run the tests.
Picking the random VDI means will not have standard username and password to login into application and I cannot manually enter username password because we use auto authentications(application logs in based on windows profile). My plan is to create some service account and provide access to that service account.
Since the service account do not match with VDI profile. Is there any way I can make use of chrome custom profile where chrome driver wouldn't take default window profile and take custom profile related to service accounts and start executing the tests?

I am new to this automating this way. Request you to provide detailed answer if possible.

Comment: Sorry.. can you tell me what is VDI? Is that virtual machine?

Comment: do you mean how to set custom profile when using chrome driver?

Comment: VDI means Virtual desktop infrastructure... Yes, looking for more examples on how to utilise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are looking for a way to use custom profile with chrome driver. That can be achieved by setting `user-data-dir` through driver capabilities.

Following example will set user data directory `mychromeprofile` from project root.

```
driver.name=chromeDriver
chrome.additional.capabilities = {"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["user-data-dir=${user.dir}/mychromeprofile"]}}
```

References:

1. [chromedriver capabilities](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)
2. [setting driver capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html)

Comment: Could you please provide examples for your explanation... I am not sure how to apply?